# Gitlab dependencies between downstream jobs

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to create the following pipeline:

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
  - deploy
  - quality

deploy_downstream:
  stage: deploy
  trigger:
    include: .gitlab-ci/deploy.yml
    strategy: depend

quality_downstream:
  stage: quality
  allow_failure: false
  rules:
    - when: manual
  trigger:
    include: .gitlab-ci/quality.yml
    strategy: depend
  needs: [ deploy_job ] # This is the job located in the deploy.yml
```

deploy.yml

```
stages:
  - deploy
  - after_deploy

deploy_job:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "deploy job"
  rules:
    - when: manual

after_deploy: 
  stage: after_deploy
  script:
   - echo "after_deploy job"
  rules:
    - when: manual
```

quality.yml

```
stages:
  - quality

automated_test:
  stage: quality
  script:
    - echo "automated_test job"
  rules:
    - when: on_success
```

What I want to achieve here is to be able to trigger the `quality` downstream even if the `after_deploy` job is not executed in the `deploy` downstream.

With the need clause but I could not make it work. Does somebody has any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: I have sucessfully achived "connection" between a downstream pipeline's job (via trigger job) with this:
```
needs:
  - pipeline: trigger_job
    job: job_name_in_downsream
    artifacts: true
```
However this seems buggy because I get: This job depends on other jobs with expired/erased artifacts:"